Error with libnftnl on Ubuntu 20.04. /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnftnl
I try to build a C program that uses the libnftnl library, but I get this error:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnftnl

Here is the way that I compile my code:
LIBS = -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmnl.so -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnftnl.so  -lmnl -lnftnl
CFLAGS = -static -s
prog:
    gcc -o prog prog.c $(LIBS) $(CFLAGS)

I install:
libnftnl-dev - Development files for libnftnl
libnftnl11 - Netfilter nftables userspace API library
But I still get the same error. What am I doing wrong?

This is wrong: -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnftnl.so (the -L before that as well): you have to pass the directory where the shared libraries are located, not the library itself. -L is a search path for the linker, in which directory/ies to look.

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ tends to be a default search path, so you wouldn't even need it. Check the contents of the files in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/, probably one of them contains that directory.

Can you compile with --verbose and show the output (probably just the last bits): I'd like to see the call to the linker.

What OS are you on? Can you show the output of ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnftnl*?

Also, I can use pkg-config --libs libnftnl (which simply outputs -lnftnl, perhaps you can as well.

You are specifying -static among your compile flags, but you seem to be expecting to link shared libraries.  That won't work -- the libraries you need for static linking are of a different kind, and their contents are built differently.  The linker knows this, so when you ask for -lnftnl in -static mode, it doesn't even consider shared libraries.
Ubuntu Focal's libnftnl-dev provides header files, an unversioned library symlink to the shared library provided by libnftnl11, and a few ancillary files.  Neither package provides a static version of the library.  This is why the linker does not find one, despite you having those packages installed.
Your easiest way forward would be to ditch -static, and instead link against the shared libraries you already have.  Here's a revised version of your makefile that specifies that, in addition to some other improvements:
LIBS = -lmnl -lnftnl
CFLAGS =
prog: prog.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LIBS)

If you insist on building a static executable, then you'll need also to build your own copy of libnftl to provide a static version of the library.  That might not be straightforward.  And you might also need to do the same for libmnl.
